# Batch Write to Firestore with Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a very large ASCII flat file (1.5 million lines) that I need to read from. It's basically a list of parts from a manufacturer. I would like to use Firestore to host it.

As a .csv file, it weighs in at 250GB. I was able to convert it into a JSON file with Windows PowerShell and now it weighs in at over 1GB.

How to get that data into Firestore? I figure the Admin SDK and a batched write would be the way to go. So, I got it all setup and a node script assembled but the Admin SDK documentation for Firestore is thin.

My node script is below but it throws error `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./--------------------------.json");
var fs = require('fs');
var myCsvFile = "./global.csv"
var parse = require('csv-parse');
require('should');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://g--------b.firebaseio.com"
});

var firestore = admin.firestore();
var writeBatch = firestore.batch();
var myRef = firestore.collection("foo").doc();
var obj = {};


fs.createReadStream(myCsvFile)
    .pipe(parse({delimiter: '|',relax_column_count:true,quote: ''}))
    .on('data', function(csvrow) {
        if(csvrow[1]){
            obj.family = csvrow[1];
        }
        if(csvrow[2]){
            obj.series = csvrow[2];
        }
        if(csvrow[3]){
            obj.sku = csvrow[3];
        }
        if(csvrow[5]){
            obj.description = csvrow[5];
        }
        if(csvrow[7]){
            obj.price = csvrow[7];  
        }
        writeBatch.set(myRef, obj);
    })
    .on('end',function() {
      writeBatch.commit()
    });
```

Comment: Hey Ron. Taking down Firestore itself seems *very* unlikely. If you manage to do so, let me know and I'll owe you one. :-)   You're most likely to run out of memory on your own laptop, which (while annoying) is also quite non-destructive. So overall, give it a try and if you get stuck post back what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" ...it's 1.5 million records (sku, description, series, family, price). ...I'm wondering if I could create the JSON file on my machine, could I upload that at once - rather than trying to batch write each line...?

Comment: Hmm... that library looks like it should be streaming, but clearly you're still running out of memory. You might want to look at our streaming import library for the realtime database, which streams the JSON you provide instead of reading it in one go.

Comment: Oh wait, I now see that you only commit the batch in `.on('end'`. That means that you're building a single batch out of the entire CSV. You'll want to keep a counter of the number of items you added to the batch and the commit it in `.on('data'` when you've added a few hundred rows/documents to it).

Comment: That's per doc. Are you writing all CSV data to one doc? Because then you'll definitely run into the 1MB per doc limit quickly.

Comment: importing a smaller (few thousand records now) I ran up against `Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call`, ...so you're right, looks like you can write 500 at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 entries can be written per second. So, the key is to rate limit the `.commit` to 1 per second and to limit the `batch.set` to under 500 per commit. I got this working with aynch/await as the rate limiter along with `promise.all` style pattern of pushing the `.set`'s into an incrementing array of `.batch`es.

Oh, and last thing - I had to tell Node to use more memory with the `--max-old-space-size` switch.

The script below was copied from [High Tech Telecom](https://hightechtele.com/articles/firebase-admin-sdk-bulk-import):

> ```
> var admin = require("firebase-admin");
> var serviceAccount = require("./your-firebase-project-service-account-key.json");
> var fs = require('fs');
> var csvFile = "./my-huge-file.csv"
> var parse = require('csv-parse');
> require('should');
>
> admin.initializeApp({
>   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
>   databaseURL: "https://your-project.firebaseio.com"
> });
>
> var firestore = admin.firestore();
> var thisRef;
> var obj = {};
> var counter = 0;
> var commitCounter = 0;
> var batches = [];
> batches[commitCounter] = firestore.batch();
>
> fs.createReadStream(csvFile)
>     .pipe(
>       parse({delimiter: '|',relax_column_count:true,quote: ''})
>   )
>     .on('data', function(csvrow) {
>       if(counter <= 498){
>           if(csvrow[1]){
>               obj.family = csvrow[1];
>           }
>           if(csvrow[2]){
>               obj.series = csvrow[2];
>           }
>           if(csvrow[3]){
>               obj.sku = csvrow[3];
>           }
>           if(csvrow[4]){
>               obj.description = csvrow[4];
>           }
>           if(csvrow[6]){
>               obj.price = csvrow[6];  
>           }
>           thisRef = firestore.collection("your-collection-name").doc();
>           batches[commitCounter].set(thisRef, obj);
>           counter = counter + 1;          
>       } else {
>           counter = 0;
>           commitCounter = commitCounter + 1;
>           batches[commitCounter] = firestore.batch();
>       }
>     })
>     .on('end',function() {
>       writeToDb(batches);
>     });
>
> function oneSecond() {
>   return new Promise(resolve => {
>       setTimeout(() => {
>           resolve('resolved');
>       }, 1010);
>   });
> }
>
> async function writeToDb(arr) {
>   console.log("beginning write");
>   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>       await oneSecond();
>       arr[i].commit().then(function () {
>           console.log("wrote batch " + i);
>       });
>   }
>   console.log("done.");
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Batch writes within the stated limits won't cause any problems in your case.  I don't think you have any alternatives, currently.

Comment: It's 1.5 million lines, or rows. I've got the node script figured out re getting at the particular fields in each line. Now I've just got to get it into Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

A short remark: You never reset obj (obj={}), so basically you insert the same record all the time.